# What does stringWithFormat:@"%1$@%2$d" do?

Tags: objective-c

```
stack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1$@%2$d", stack, number];
```

I'm following a Xcode calculator tutorial, and I'm not too sure what does the `%1$@%2$d` represents. Please guide me.

Comment: [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1)

Answer (score 2):

`%@` says the argument is an Objective-C object and it sends one of the description selectors to get the string that will be inserted into the final string.

`%1$@` says the same thing, but specifies the first argument.

`%d` is a signed, 32-bit integer.

`%2$d` specifies the second argument is a signed, 32-bit integer.

Answer (score 1):

This format is used to explicitly select which argument should be replaced in the string so `1$` is for the first argument, `2$` for the 2nd etc...

The `'@'` is for ObjC objects (which in general displayes an object's description), and `'d'` is for integers

In this case it could also be written simply as :

```
stack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", stack, number];
```

Comment: But, it's not `$1`, it's `1$`

Comment: :) - Must've been doing too much swift!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know what `%@` and `%d` mean. By default, the first specifier(such as `%@`) will be replaced by the value of the first argument in argument list, and so on. However, `n$` gives you the power to specify the argument at which position you want to use its value to replace the specifier containing `n$`.

In fact, a simple example is much clearer:

```
NSString *aString = @"ultimate answer";
int anInteger = 42;
NSLog(@"The %@ is %d.", aString, anInteger); // The ultimate answer is 42.
NSLog(@"The %1$@ is %2$d.", aString, anInteger); // The ultimate answer is 42.
NSLog(@"%2$d is the %1$@.", aString, anInteger); // 42 is the ultimate answer.
```

Answer (score -2):

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1$@%2$d", stack, number];
```

breaks down logically to mean you want a string (you get that from string with format), displaying two items (you can see that from the items after the string, and the number of % symbols in the format.

%1$@%2$d is for two items, you can break them by the %, %1 and %2 mean first and second.

%1$@ - @ represents an object that wil be translated to a string

%2$d - d represents a decimal.

Comment: not sure why this question was not closed already. or why people do not like my answer.